# Studio3T Import SQL to MongoDB multiple tables

Tags: sql, mongodb, studio3t

Is it possible to import more than one table at a time from SQL to MongoDB using Studio3T?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. And you can also change the number of processors dedicated to the import or export in the studio3t preferences. Look for the "Background" tab.

[image]